# How to build an LLVM/CLANG aarch64 cross-compiler for use on x86?

Tags: build, clang, llvm, cross-compiling

There are two different kind of compilers:

- **(I)** host compiler (may be used, for example, on x86, arm, aarch64 PC to compile binaries for the same platform)
- **(II)** cross-compiler (may be used, for example, on x86 PC to generate aarch64 binary)

I found a lot of information about how to build LLVM/Clang toolchain, for example on x86 PC to get LLVM/Clang toolchain which will be able to to work on aarch64 PC. This is "**(I)**" kind of compiler.

At the same time, I haven't found information, sufficient to build a compiler of "**(II)**" kind (cross-compiler).

Specifically, I am looking for the instructions of how to build aarch64 cross-compiler, which is possible to run on x86 platform to generate aarch64 binary.

P.S.

I've tried to build LLVM/Clang cross compiler via command:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="../dist" \
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="AArch64" \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld;llvm" \
-DLLVM_BUILD_TOOLS="ON" \
-DLLVM_BINUTILS_INCDIR="../../binutils-gdb/include" \
-DLLVM_INSTALL_BINUTILS_SYMLINKS="ON" \
-DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB="YES" \
-DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold \
-DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF \
-DLLVM_INCLUDE_BENCHMARKS=OFF \
-DLLVM_APPEND_VC_REV=OFF \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_LIBPFM=OFF \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_DIA_SDK=OFF \
../../llvm-project/llvm \
&& \
make
```

Unfortunately, it was impossible to build simple C source file (it calls GCC...):

```
$ /PATH/TO/bin/clang-17 --target=aarch64-unknown-vendor-gnueabi -o main.o main.c

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-fbdd09.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-fbdd09.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
clang-17: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, it was possible to build an executable if to run compilation and link commands separately:

```
$ /PATH/TO/bin/clang-17 --target=aarch64-unknown-vendor-gnueabi -c main.c

$ /PATH/TO/bin/ld.lld -o main main.o

ld.lld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

Comment: You don't need to build Clang yourself to cross-compile. Just take the existing Clang and pass `--target` and `--sysroot` to it, and it'll act as a cross-compiler.

Comment: What OS are you trying to cross-compile for?

Comment: Our team needs to build CLANG themselves to test features that have not yet been released by the CLANG team.